# If suspended process is killed then the program is running or not?

Tags: linux, shell, command

If I ***suspend the process*** called firefox let's say, using `ctrl+z` **in Linux**.
and later i ***killed the process*** with `#kill -9 <3643>`, then the program firefox is in ***running state or not***?

*3643 is a process ID given by command #pgrep firefox.

Answer (score 1):

At least on Linux, of you suspend a program with Ctrl-Z (which sends `SIGTSTP`, I think), or with `SIGSTOP`, and it goes in the `T` state, then

- shooting it with `SIGTERM` (`kill $pid`) will do nothing immediately. It just queues the signal, which will be dealt with when the process continues. The process might have installed a handler for the signal.
- shooting it with `SIGKILL` (`kill -9 $pid`) should kill it, before waiting for anything else, since that signal can't be caught. (How immediate that might actually be on a loaded system, I don't know.)

However, if the process is in the `D` state ("uninterruptible sleep", usual  I/O-related), then even `SIGKILL` might not kill it until whatever it's waiting for resolves.